# fread, filesize usage with remote picture

Tags: php, mysql, twitter, filesize, fread

I'm doing a script that takes the image from Twitter API, and return's it on base64, but I have troubles because the file is on a remote server (Twitter). Here I show the code, the main problem is with the `fread()` and `filesize()`. I get this:

`Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/...jpg in...`

```
<?
mysql_connect...;
mysql_select_db...;
$autho_name = ...;
include '../twitter/LibTwitter.php';
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY id DESC");
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
$userid = $result["userid"];
$busqueda = $twitter->usersShow($userid);
$username = $busqueda["screen_name"];
$img_src = str_replace("_normal.", "_reasonably_small.", $busqueda["profile_image_url"]);
$imgbinary = fread(fopen($img_src, "r"), filesize($img_src));
$img_str = base64_encode($imgbinary);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.$img_str.'" />';
}
?>
```

I replaced personal data with ... because of obvious reasons, no problem with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `file_get_contents()` to fetch the image, then it's a simple matter of:

```
$img = file_get_contents('http://a0.twimg...etc....');
$size = strlen($img);
$base64 = base64_encode($img);
```